# Rails: accepts_nested_attributes_for with "strong parameters" requiring IDs in params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

Suppose a model `Book`, with:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: pages
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pages
```

To UPDATE a `Page` record instead of CREATING a new one, Rails requires the ID of the nested model (here: `Page`) to be allowed in the "strong parameters" (of the `Book` instance):

```
def update
  @book.update(book_params)
end

private

  def book_params()
    params.require(:book).permit(:title, :author, :published,
      pages_attributes: [:id, :word_count, :line_count]) #  <= this ID in here
  end
```

But doesn't the inclusion of `ID`s in the "strong parameters" defeat their purpose? (Meaning: a user could submit a false `ID`, causing a wrong association.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails makes sure the page you're trying to update belongs to the book. If you tried changing page ID in the form, you would get an error:

> Couldn't find Page with ID=3 for Book with ID=1